# Encoding WAV file cuts off early

Tags: c++, linux, audio, wav, alsa

In my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395980/record-into-wav-file), I managed to get a working `.wav` file as the output.  However, when I throw this `.wav` file into my encoder (tested with other `.wav` files and works perfectly), my encoder throws back an error back at me right before it finishes.

Here is my output:

```
$ ./capture 2
Capture device is plughw:1,0    
Finished writing to /tmp/filevXDDX6.wav
Starting encode to /tmp/filevXDDX6.flac
Wrote 3641 bytes, 4096/88200 samples, 2/22 frames
Wrote 6132 bytes, 8192/88200 samples, 2/22 frames
Wrote 8748 bytes, 12288/88200 samples, 3/22 frames
Wrote 11253 bytes, 16384/88200 samples, 4/22 frames
Wrote 13697 bytes, 20480/88200 samples, 5/22 frames
Wrote 16222 bytes, 24576/88200 samples, 6/22 frames
Wrote 18811 bytes, 28672/88200 samples, 7/22 frames
Wrote 21900 bytes, 32768/88200 samples, 8/22 frames
Wrote 24681 bytes, 36864/88200 samples, 9/22 frames
Wrote 27408 bytes, 40960/88200 samples, 10/22 frames
Wrote 30494 bytes, 45056/88200 samples, 11/22 frames
Wrote 34107 bytes, 49152/88200 samples, 12/22 frames
Wrote 37447 bytes, 53248/88200 samples, 13/22 frames
Wrote 40719 bytes, 57344/88200 samples, 14/22 frames
Wrote 45257 bytes, 61440/88200 samples, 15/22 frames
Wrote 48735 bytes, 65536/88200 samples, 16/22 frames
Wrote 52842 bytes, 69632/88200 samples, 17/22 frames
Wrote 56529 bytes, 73728/88200 samples, 18/22 frames
Wrote 60185 bytes, 77824/88200 samples, 19/22 frames
Wrote 63906 bytes, 81920/88200 samples, 20/22 frames
ERROR: reading from WAVE file
Wrote 67687 bytes, 86016/88200 samples, 21/22 frames
Encoding: FAILED
   State: FLAC__STREAM_ENCODER_UNINITIALIZED
```

I'm not sure why it's cutting off early, though I'm pretty sure it has to do with how I'm trying to record my own `.wav` file (since my encoder worked fine with other files).

Here is my code (sorry it's a bit long, I cut down as much as possible):

```cpp
// Compile with "g++ test.ccp -o test -lasound"

// Use the newer ALSA API
#define ALSA_PCM_NEW_HW_PARAMS_API

#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct WaveHeader
{
        char RIFF_marker[4];
        uint32_t file_size;
        char filetype_header[4];
        char format_marker[4];
        uint32_t data_header_length;
        uint16_t format_type;
        uint16_t number_of_channels;
        uint32_t sample_rate;
        uint32_t bytes_per_second;
        uint16_t bytes_per_frame;
        uint16_t bits_per_sample;
};

struct WaveHeader *genericWAVHeader(uint32_t sample_rate, uint16_t bit_depth, uint16_t channels)
{
    struct WaveHeader *hdr;
    hdr = (WaveHeader*) malloc(sizeof(*hdr));
    if (!hdr)
        return NULL;

    memcpy(&hdr->RIFF_marker, "RIFF", 4);
    memcpy(&hdr->filetype_header, "WAVE", 4);
    memcpy(&hdr->format_marker, "fmt ", 4);
    hdr->data_header_length = 16;
    hdr->format_type = 1;
    hdr->number_of_channels = channels;
    hdr->sample_rate = sample_rate;
    hdr->bytes_per_second = sample_rate * channels * bit_depth / 8;
    hdr->bytes_per_frame = channels * bit_depth / 8;
    hdr->bits_per_sample = bit_depth;

    return hdr;
}

int writeWAVHeader(int fd, struct WaveHeader *hdr)
{
    if (!hdr)
        return -1;

    write(fd, &hdr->RIFF_marker, 4);
    write(fd, &hdr->file_size, 4);
    write(fd, &hdr->filetype_header, 4);
    write(fd, &hdr->format_marker, 4);
    write(fd, &hdr->data_header_length, 4);
    write(fd, &hdr->format_type, 2);
    write(fd, &hdr->number_of_channels, 2);
    write(fd, &hdr->sample_rate, 4);
    write(fd, &hdr->bytes_per_second, 4);
    write(fd, &hdr->bytes_per_frame, 2);
    write(fd, &hdr->bits_per_sample, 2);
    write(fd, "data", 4);

    uint32_t data_size = hdr->file_size + 8 - 44;
    write(fd, &data_size, 4);

    return 0;
}

int recordWAV(const char *fileName, struct WaveHeader *hdr, uint32_t duration)
{
    int err;
    int size;
    snd_pcm_t *handle;
    snd_pcm_hw_params_t *params;
    unsigned int sampleRate = hdr->sample_rate;
    int dir;
    snd_pcm_uframes_t frames = 32;
    char *device = (char*) "plughw:1,0";
    char *buffer;
    int filedesc;

    printf("Capture device is %s\n", device);

    /* Open PCM device for recording (capture). */
    err = snd_pcm_open(&handle, device, SND_PCM_STREAM_CAPTURE, 0);
    if (err)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open PCM device: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
        return err;
    }

    /* Allocate a hardware parameters object. */
    snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&params);

    /* Fill it in with default values. */
    snd_pcm_hw_params_any(handle, params);

    /* ### Set the desired hardware parameters. ### */

    /* Interleaved mode */
    err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access(handle, params, SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED);
    if (err)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting interleaved mode: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
        snd_pcm_close(handle);
        return err;
    }
    /* Signed 16-bit little-endian format */
    if (hdr->bits_per_sample == 16) err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(handle, params, SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE);
    else err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(handle, params, SND_PCM_FORMAT_U8);
    if (err)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting format: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
        snd_pcm_close(handle);
        return err;
    }
    /* Two channels (stereo) */
    err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(handle, params, hdr->number_of_channels);
    if (err)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting channels: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
        snd_pcm_close(handle);
        return err;
    }
    /* 44100 bits/second sampling rate (CD quality) */
    sampleRate = hdr->sample_rate;
    err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near(handle, params, &sampleRate, &dir);
    if (err)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting sampling rate (%d): %s\n", sampleRate, snd_strerror(err));
        snd_pcm_close(handle);
        return err;
    }
    hdr->sample_rate = sampleRate;
    /* Set period size*/
    err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near(handle, params, &frames, &dir);
    if (err)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting period size: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
        snd_pcm_close(handle);
        return err;
    }
    /* Write the parameters to the driver */
    err = snd_pcm_hw_params(handle, params);
    if (err < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to set HW parameters: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
        snd_pcm_close(handle);
        return err;
    }

    /* Use a buffer large enough to hold one period */
    err = snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size(params, &frames, &dir);
    if (err)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error retrieving period size: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
        snd_pcm_close(handle);
        return err;
    }

    size = frames * hdr->bits_per_sample / 8 * hdr->number_of_channels; /* 2 bytes/sample, 2 channels */
    buffer = (char *) malloc(size);
    if (!buffer)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "Buffer error.\n");
        snd_pcm_close(handle);
        return -1;
    }

    err = snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_time(params, &sampleRate, &dir);
    if (err)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error retrieving period time: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
        snd_pcm_close(handle);
        free(buffer);
        return err;
    }

    uint32_t pcm_data_size = hdr->sample_rate * hdr->bytes_per_frame * duration / 1000;
    hdr->file_size = pcm_data_size + 44 - 8;

    filedesc = open(fileName, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644);
    err = writeWAVHeader(filedesc, hdr);
    if (err)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error writing .wav header.");
        snd_pcm_close(handle);
        free(buffer);
        close(filedesc);
        return err;
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "Channels: %d\n", hdr->number_of_channels);
    for(int i = duration * 1000 / sampleRate; i > 0; i--)
    {
        err = snd_pcm_readi(handle, buffer, frames);
        if (err == -EPIPE) fprintf(stderr, "Overrun occurred: %d\n", err);
        if (err < 0) err = snd_pcm_recover(handle, err, 0);

        // Still an error, need to exit.
        if (err < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error occured while recording: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
            snd_pcm_close(handle);
            free(buffer);
            close(filedesc);
            return err;
        }
        write(filedesc, buffer, size);
    }

    close(filedesc);
    snd_pcm_drain(handle);
    snd_pcm_close(handle);
    free(buffer);

    printf("Finished writing to %s\n", fileName);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{

    if(argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s (record duration)\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    int err;
    struct WaveHeader *hdr;

    // Creates a temporary file in /tmp

    char wavFile[L_tmpnam + 5];
    char *tempFilenameStub = tmpnam(NULL);
    sprintf(wavFile, "%s.wav", tempFilenameStub);
    hdr = genericWAVHeader(44000, 16, 2);
    if (!hdr)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating WAV header.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    err = recordWAV(wavFile, hdr, 1000 * strtod(argv[1], NULL));
    if (err)
    {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error recording WAV file: %d\n", err);
            return err;
    }

    free(hdr);
    return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions?

---

**Edit** - I was told to compare the headers of my `.wav` file to that of one generated by `arecord`.  Here are the results:

```
$ stat -c %s arecord.wav
352844

$ stat -c %s /tmp/filevXDDX6.wav
345004

$ xxd -g1 arecord.wav | head
0000000: 52 49 46 46 44 62 05 00 57 41 56 45 66 6d 74 20  RIFFDb..WAVEfmt
0000010: 10 00 00 00 01 00 02 00 44 ac 00 00 10 b1 02 00  ........D.......
0000020: 04 00 10 00 64 61 74 61 20 62 05 00 08 00 08 00  ....data b......
0000030: 08 00 08 00 07 00 07 00 fe ff fe ff f7 ff f7 ff  ................
0000040: f6 ff f6 ff ee ff ee ff ee ff ee ff f6 ff f6 ff  ................
0000050: f0 ff f0 ff e7 ff e7 ff ee ff ee ff f4 ff f4 ff  ................
0000060: f4 ff f4 ff f7 ff f7 ff fe ff fe ff fc ff fc ff  ................
0000070: fa ff fa ff f5 ff f5 ff ed ff ed ff ee ff ee ff  ................
0000080: f8 ff f8 ff f4 ff f4 ff ed ff ed ff ee ff ee ff  ................
0000090: f8 ff f8 ff f6 ff f6 ff f0 ff f0 ff ee ff ee ff  ................

$ xxd -g1 /tmp/filevXDDX6.wav | head
0000000: 52 49 46 46 44 62 05 00 57 41 56 45 66 6d 74 20  RIFFDb..WAVEfmt
0000010: 10 00 00 00 01 00 02 00 44 ac 00 00 10 b1 02 00  ........D.......
0000020: 04 00 10 00 64 61 74 61 20 62 05 00 71 00 71 00  ....data b..q.q.
0000030: 6f 00 6f 00 79 00 79 00 75 00 75 00 63 00 63 00  o.o.y.y.u.u.c.c.
0000040: 3e 00 3e 00 1b 00 1b 00 07 00 07 00 fb ff fb ff  >.>.............
0000050: 00 00 00 00 0c 00 0c 00 0f 00 0f 00 1c 00 1c 00  ................
0000060: 30 00 30 00 31 00 31 00 24 00 24 00 1e 00 1e 00  0.0.1.1.$.$.....
0000070: 24 00 24 00 31 00 31 00 2c 00 2c 00 28 00 28 00  $.$.1.1.,.,.(.(.
0000080: 31 00 31 00 3c 00 3c 00 36 00 36 00 31 00 31 00  1.1.<.<.6.6.1.1.
0000090: 39 00 39 00 40 00 40 00 3d 00 3d 00 30 00 30 00  9.9.@.@.=.=.0.0.

$ file arecord.wav
test.wav: RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 16 bit, stereo 44100 Hz

$ file /tmp/filevXDDX6.wav                        
/tmp/filevXDDX6.wav: RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 16 bit, stereo 44100 Hz
```

Comment: @CL. Are you sure the headers will be the difference and not the actual data?

Comment: Failing between a write of 63906 bytes and 67687 bytes - which is suspiciously around `2^16`. is an `unsigned short` overflowing here?

Comment: @Marko I'm pretty sure.  The bytes are being stored in unsigned `int`s.  Also, if I change the amount of seconds I record to something else (such as 5), it does not fail in the same area that it does for 2 seconds (it still fails right before the last frame is encoded).

Comment: Your for loop looks off, try `for(int i = (duration * sampleRate)/1000  ; i > 0; i-=frames)`, also I think it should be `hdr->file_size = pcm_data_size + 32;`, `data_size = hdr->file_size - 32;`

Comment: @Musa The modification of the `for` loop made the error occur sooner, and I'm not sure the file_size modification did anything.  They also did not work together.

Comment: Well you should take CL advice and check your file against a valid wav file (of the same length) to see whats different.

Comment: @Musa I've done that and edited that into my question just now.  They look exactly the same.

Comment: @syb0rg Use something like `xxd -g1 test.wav | head`.

Comment: @CL. I've edited that into my question.  It looks like there is some kind of noise in my file (the data section).

Comment: A little bit of noise is normal for analog devices. Have the files exactly the same length?

Comment: @CL. Checking the file size for recording the same amount of time, no.  I've edited that into the question.  Using `soxi -D` tells me they are they both contain 2 seconds of audio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program does not write the correct number of samples to the .wav file.

`snd_pcm_readi` returns the number of frames that was actually read.
You can only write that many frames to the output.

The integer division in `duration * 1000 / sampleRate` might be rounded.
It is likely that `duration * 1000 / sampleRate * frames` is not exactly the same as the number of frames you actually want to read.

You should restructure your loop to count the total number of frames.

Comment: Alright, I figured out the `for` loop.  I had to change the sampling rate down to `44000` in order for the loop count to be nice and even, but it works.  Here's what I changed it to: `for(int i = ((duration * 1000) / (hdr->sample_rate / frames)); i > 0; i--)`.